# trying to wrap a promise with an observable

Tags: angular, promise, observable

i am trying to return an observable when promise then is triggered. 
i am using ng-bootstrap to open a modal and i want to handle the promise return via observable.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//modal/popups
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
// observable
import { Observable  } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminModalService {

  constructor(public ngbModal:NgbModal) {


  }

    open(component:any):Observable<any>{
     const modalRef = this.ngbModal.open(component); //this will return a promise
      modalRef.result.then((result) => {
              console.log('result', result);
              this.myObservable(result);
            }, (reason) => {
              //handle modal dismiss
              console.log('reason', reason);
              this.myObservable(result);
            });

    }

     myObservable(data){
        return new Observable((observer) => {
              observer.next(data);
         observer.complete();
        })
     }

}
```

this is the header component i call the observable from and also where i subscribe to it

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// components
import { ModalComponent from'../../../../shared/components/modal/modal.component';
// services
import { AdminModalService } from '../../../../shared/services/modal-service/modal-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public adminModalService: AdminModalService) {};


  ngOnInit() {
  }

openModal(){

    this.adminModalService.open(ModalComponent).subscribe(
      (res: any[]) => {
        console.log('res', res);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

this is the error i receive:  error TS2322: Type `'Promise<void>'` is not assignable to type `'Observable<any>'`.

i have been trying to accomplish this for a long time without any real progress would appreciate any help or guiding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a little more easily with the built-in `fromPromise` operator.

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable';

export class AdminModalService {

  constructor(public ngbModal:NgbModal) {


  }

    open(component:any):Observable<any>{
     const modalRef = fromPromise(this.ngbModal.open(component));

      modalRef.subscribe(/*Do your thing!*/);

    }

}
```

It does exactly what you're trying to do, but already wrapped up in a creation method.

**NOTE**: In RxJS 6.0+, the `fromPromise` functionality has been wrapped up into the `from` creation operator, so if you're at 6.0+ just use `Observable.from()` or import `from` instead.

Comment: Never subscribe your observable in service.

Comment: Agreed (unless the obx is hot); I was just demonstrating that `modalRef` was now an Observable.

Comment: In RxJS 6.0 `Observable.from()` does not exist. Use `from()` imported from `"rxjs"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake in your service open method. Never use promise in observable. Always convert your promise with observable.

```
open(component:any):Observable<any>{
     const modalRef = this.ngbModal.open(component); //this will return a promise
      return Observable.fromPromise(modalRef.result);
    }
```

In your component use like this:

```
openModal(){

    this.adminModalService.open(ModalComponent).mergeMap(result => {
      return this.adminModalService.myObservable(result);
    }).subscribe(
      (res: any[]) => {
        console.log('res', res);
      }
    );
  }
```